# pd.min() function not reading negative values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the minimum value from a dataframe:

```
    mth_ret
1   0.111587855
2   8.66E-05
3   -0.169424524
```

My Python code is:

```
df.min()
```

However, it returns `8.66E-05` as minimum value. The correct answer is `-0.169424524`.
What function should I use to get minimum value of -0.169424524?

I checked using `df.describe()`, it also prints out `8.66E-05` as minimum value.
It seems that Python is not reading `-` as negative.

Comment: are you sure? Mine it returns -0.169424524. Can you show us your entire code when you reading the file?

Comment: It works now. I have been referencing wrong column. Thanks Billy.